# Unable to Perform Time Series Forecasting using GPR on Apple Stock Exchange Data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I am implementing time series forecasting with **Gaussian Process Regression in Python on Apple Stock Price dataset**. My intention is to train the data onto a 10 year data of stock price and then predict one month in future.

Simply put I am trying to predict the future price of a stock using the last 1 year data using GPR. As an inexperienced coder I can obviously have screwed up many things. But my ultimate intention is to use the stock opening/closing/high/low prices of last 10 years to train model and then predict 1 month into future. Your advice and suggestions would be highly appreciated. Frankly speaking I have no idea how to proceed further.

The data looks like this.

[image]

I am able to get it to work on test data with close to **100% accuracy** when trained with current data data as X, and current day closing as Y.

## Here are the graphs when I do normal Test-Train split on data.

[image]

## Here's the graph when I do time series forecasting.

[image]

## Below is the data for normal Test/Train predictions

## Importing required libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
```

## Load the dataset

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
Data = pd.read_csv( os.path.join(dirname, 'APPL.csv'))

dataY = Data['Close'].values
dataX = Data.copy()
dataX = Data.drop('Close', axis=1)
dataX = Data.drop('Date', axis=1)
TrainX, TestX, TrainY, TestY  = train_test_split(dataX, dataY, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

TrainX = scaler.fit_transform(TrainX)
TestX = scaler.transform(TestX)
```

## Values of Test Data split into X and Y components

```
PlotY = []
for i in TestY: 
    PlotY.append(i)

PlotX = []
j=0
for i in TestY:
    PlotX.append(j)
    j=j+1
```

## GPR 30% Test Data Testing

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct, WhiteKernel
kernel =  WhiteKernel() + DotProduct()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gpr.fit(TrainX, TrainY)
ForecastGPR = gpr.predict(TestX)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8))
plt.plot(PlotX, PlotY, color="green", label='actual', )
plt.plot(ForecastGPR, label='Predicted', color='red', linewidth = 0.5)
plt.xlabel("Time (Days)")
plt.ylabel("Closing Price (USD)")
plt.title("GPR Predictions vs Actual Values (30% Test data)", y = -0.15)
plt.legend(['Actual Price', 'Predicted Price (GPR))'], bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0)
plt.show()
```

## Checking output

```
print("GPR R-squared", "{:.2%}".format(r2_score(TestY, ForecastGPR)))
print("The Root Mean Squared Error:", round(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(TestY, ForecastGPR)),2))
print("The Mean Absolute Error:", round(mean_absolute_error(TestY, ForecastGPR),2))
# Observed Accuracy 99.52%
```

But, then I want to predict future. So, I tried to change the dataX to days instead.

I did something like this.

**Here I am creating numpy array with total number of days. This would be my X, then I am using Stock closing price as Y. After training I am recieving an inaccurate flat line. Moreover, the future predictions are inaccurate as well**

To keep question short, I have stripped the code responsible for graph plotting.

```
l = []
Data = pd.read_csv( os.path.join(dirname, 'APPL.csv'))

dataY = Data['Close'].values
# Total rows = 2749
for i in range(2749):
    l.append(i)

dataX= np.array(l).reshape(-1, 1)

TrainX, TestX, TrainY, TestY  = train_test_split(dataX, dataY, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

TrainX = scaler.fit_transform(TrainX)
TestX = scaler.transform(TestX)
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct, WhiteKernel
kernel =  WhiteKernel() + DotProduct()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gpr.fit(TrainX, TrainY)
i = 2749
for i in range 2849
    l.append(i)
TestX = np.array(l).reshape(-1, 1)
ForecastGPR = gpr.predict(TestX)
```

Comment: what are shape: dataX, dataY?

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili 

dataX/dataY for time series forecasting are (2749, 1) and (2749,) respectively

Also, have a look at it again, I have tried to improve the question

Comment: not sure what you've tried to achieve here but:
dataX = Data.copy()
dataX = Data.drop('Close', axis=1)
dataX = Data.drop('Date', axis=1)
looks like a bug to me

Comment: @A-_-S simply put I am trying to predict the future price of a stock using the last 1 year data using GPR. As an inexperienced coder I can obviously have screwed up many things. But my ultimate intention is to use the stock opening/closing/high/low prices of last 10 years to train model and then predict 1 month into future. Your advice and suggestions would be highly appreciated. Frankly speaking I have no idea how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

I have trained time series model with Apple stock dataset for 10 years. In this model, I can forecast next 1 month of data for future date. I have used first 9 years 11 months of data for training & tested model with last 28 days which was unseen by model.

**Plot for Train-Test data**
[image]

**Plot for Forecast period**
[image]

You can try this code below,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

Data_ori = yf.download(tickers=['AAPL'], period='10y')
Data_test=Data_ori[2491:2519]
Data= Data_ori.iloc[0:2490]
dataY = Data['Close'].values
dataX = Data.copy()
dataX = Data.drop('Close', axis=1)
#dataX = Data.drop('Date', axis=1)
TrainX, TestX, TrainY, TestY  = train_test_split(dataX, dataY, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=42, shuffle=False)

TrainX = scaler.fit_transform(TrainX)
TestX = scaler.transform(TestX)
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct, WhiteKernel
kernel =  WhiteKernel() + DotProduct()
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)
gpr.fit(TrainX, TrainY)
ForecastGPR = gpr.predict(TestX)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
plt.plot(PlotX, PlotY, color="green", label='actual', )
plt.plot(ForecastGPR, label='Predicted', color='red', linewidth = 0.5)
plt.xlabel("Time (Days)")
plt.ylabel("Closing Price (USD)")
plt.title("GPR Predictions vs Actual Values (30% Test data)", y = -0.15)
plt.legend(['Actual Price', 'Predicted Price (GPR))'], bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 
1., .102), loc=3, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0)
plt.show()

#Test model
dataY1 = Data_test['Close'].values
dataX1 = Data_test.copy()
dataX1 = Data_test.drop('Close', axis=1)
PlotY = []

for i in dataY1: 
    PlotY.append(i)

PlotX = []
j=0
for i in dataY1:
    PlotX.append(j)
    j=j+1

ForecastGPR1 = gpr.predict(TestX1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
plt.plot(PlotX, PlotY, color="green", label='actual', )
plt.plot(ForecastGPR1, label='Predicted', color='red', linewidth = 0.5)
plt.xlabel("Time (Days)")
plt.ylabel("Closing Price (USD)")
plt.title("GPR Predictions vs Actual Values (30% Test data)", y = -0.15)
plt.legend(['Actual Price', 'Predicted Price (GPR))'], bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 
1., .102), loc=3, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey there... Thanks.... My intention is to use 9 yrs+ 11 months of data... And then test it with 1 month of unseen data and then somehow perform "forecasting" that is predicting in future.

Let's say today is 25th Feb, so I train it from 2010 to today, and then predict till end of march, 2023 (which is yet to come).

I know it sounds tough, but considering it is a normal college assignment, I think there should be an easy way around to implement it.

Comment: Hey Aditya, I have trained model for 9 yrs 11 month of data. I have forecasted for Feb 2023. If you want to forecast for March 2023 , you need to have independent variables except 'Close' feature.  I suggest you to try out with LSTM or Facebook Prophet model to get better results for time series data. Hope I have clarified your question.